# Turning a string with brackets and parentheses into a nested list

Tags: r

Consider the following string:

```
x = "a (b, c), d [e, f (g, h)], i (j, k (l (m, n [o, p])))"
```

My goal is to take this string and turn it into the following list:

```
list("a" = list("b", "c"),
     "d" = list("e", "f" = list("g", "h")),
     "i" = list("j", "k" = list("l" = list("m", "n" = list("o", "p")))))

$a
$a[[1]]
[1] "b"

$a[[2]]
[1] "c"


$d
$d[[1]]
[1] "e"

$d$f
$d$f[[1]]
[1] "g"

$d$f[[2]]
[1] "h"



$i
$i[[1]]
[1] "j"

$i$k
$i$k$l
$i$k$l[[1]]
[1] "m"

$i$k$l$n
$i$k$l$n[[1]]
[1] "o"

$i$k$l$n[[2]]
[1] "p"
```

The first issue is to deal with trying to separate each component:

```
x = "a (b, c), d [e, f (g, h)], i (j, k (l (m, n [o, p])))"

str_split_quotes = function(s) {
  o = el(strsplit(s, split = "(?<=\\)|\\]),", perl = T))
  lapply(o, function(z) gsub(pattern = " ", "", z))
}

str_unparse_level = function(s) {
  
  check_parsed = function(s) {
    grepl("\\)|\\]", s)
  }
  
  parse = function(s)  {
    if (check_parsed(s)) {
      substring_name    = substr(s, 1, 1)
      substring_content = substr(s, 3, nchar(s) - 1)
      substring_content_split = el(strsplit(substring_content, ",(?![^()]*+\\))", perl = T))
      o = list(substring_content_split)
      names(o) = substring_name
      return(o)}
    else {return(s)}
  }
  
  lapply(s, parse)
}

str_unparse_level(str_split_quotes(x))
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] "b" "c"


[[2]]
[[2]]$d
[1] "e"      "f(g,h)"


[[3]]
[[3]]$i
[1] "j"              "k(l(m,n[o,p]))"
```

Intuitively, what needs to happen here is that some sort of function involving recursion (due to the variable depth of nesting of parentheses/brackets) will need to be executed here so that a list can be created, as I seek above. It is not clear to me how to go about this, given that I rarely use recursion.

Comment: You don't need recursion. It's a know problem related to  "balanced brackets in an expression". The approach is to go through your string and put opening brackets - ( and [ - in a stack and when you come to a closing brackets you process the expression between the closing bracket and last opening brackets in the stack. And so until the stack is empty. Then your go further through the string and process next expression. In your case the stack probably will be an object with two fields - opening bracket and part of the string after it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to use `eval(parse` after modifying the `(` and `[` with `list`

```
out <- eval(parse(text = gsub('(\\w+)', '"\\1"', 
   paste0("list(", gsub("\\(", "=list(", chartr("[]", "()", x)), 
      ")"))))
```

-checking with OP's output

```
> op_out <- list("a" = list("b", "c"),
+                "d" = list("e", "f" = list("g", "h")),
+                "i" = list("j", "k" = list("l" = list("m", "n" = list("o", "p")))))
> all.equal(out, op_out)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Add a root node making it valid R syntax and replace the square brackets with parentheses for simpler processing later.  Then parse the result giving `p` and walk the parse tree using recursive function `rec` giving the result.  This avoids invoking `eval`, the use of which is sometimes discouraged.

```
rec <- function(x) {
    if (length(x) == 1) list(as.character(x))
    else {
      L <- sapply(as.list(x)[-1], rec)
      setNames(list(L), as.character(x[[1]])[[1]])
    }
  }

x <- "a (b, c), d [e, f (g, h)], i (j, k (l (m, n [o, p])))"

p <- chartr("[]", "()", x) |>
  sprintf(fmt = "root(%s)") |>
  parse(text = _)
res <- rec(p[[1]])[[1]]

str(res)
```

giving

```
List of 3
 $ a:List of 2
  ..$ : chr "b"
  ..$ : chr "c"
 $ d:List of 2
  ..$  : chr "e"
  ..$ f:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "g"
  .. ..$ : chr "h"
 $ i:List of 2
  ..$  : chr "j"
  ..$ k:List of 1
  .. ..$ l:List of 2
  .. .. ..$  : chr "m"
  .. .. ..$ n:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "o"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "p"
```

**2)** Here is a variation that converts the input to a tcl object and then walks that instead.  `parse` is not used.

```
library(tcltk)

tt <- x |>
  chartr("()[],", "{}{} ", x = _) |>
  gsub("(\\w+) +\\{", "\\{\\1 ", x = _) |>
  sprintf(fmt = "set s {root %s}") |>
  .Tcl()

fun <- function(x) {
  n <- as.numeric(tcl("llength", x))
  if (n == 1) list(as.character(tcl("lindex", x, 0)))
  else {
    L <- sapply(2:n, function(i)print( fun(tcl("lindex", x, i - 1))))
    setNames(list(L), as.character(tcl("lindex", x, 0)))
  }
}

x <- "a (b, c), d [e, f (g, h)], i (j, k (l (m, n [o, p])))"
res <- fun(tt)[[1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a parser that uses a bit of recursion to parse the string

```
parse_list <- function(x) {
  opens <- c("(", "[")
  closes  <- c(")", "]")
  tokens <- Filter(\(x) x!= " ", strsplit(x, "")[[1]])
  maybenames <- function(values, names) if (any(names!="")) setNames(values, names) else values
  inner <- function(start=1) {
    i <- start
    names <- character()
    values <- list()
    while (i <= length(tokens)) {
      if (i < length(tokens)-1 && tokens[i+1] %in% opens) {
        name <- tokens[i]
        i <- i + 1
        opener <- tokens[i]
        i <- i + 1
        result <- inner(i)
        names <- c(names, name)
        values <- c(values, list(result$value))
        i <- result$resume
        closer <- tokens[i]
      } else if (tokens[i] == ",") {
        # next item
      } else if (tokens[i] %in% closes) {
        return(list(value=maybenames(values, names), resume = i))
      } else {
        names <- c(names, "")
        values <- c(values, list(tokens[i]))
      }
      i <- i + 1
    }
    return(maybenames(values, names))
  }
  inner()
}
```

And you can call it like

```
x = "a (b, c), d [e, f (g, h)], i (j, k (l (m, n [o, p])))"
parse_list(x)
```

This does make the strong assumption that all your labels are single characters, if that's not the case, you'll need to adjust the `tokens` variable to do whatever splitting is required. There's not really any validation or error checking in place. You may want to add that as well.